# Apache rewrite: if not exists in /public open as /public/index.php/

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I want

1. `http://kemtime2_neu.pr.domain.de/css/style.css` to open as `http://kemtime2_neu.pr.domain.de/public/css/style.css` and
2. `http://kemtime2_neu.pr.domain.de/login` to open as `http://kemtime2_neu.pr.domain.de/public/index.php/login`

I have

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/index.php/$1 [L]
```

This works for 2.

How do I make it work for 1.? Note that I can not change the document root (sorry!).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it:

```
# Redirect to static content
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond /var/www/de/domain/pr/kemtime2_neu/public%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /public/$1 [L]

# otherwise redirect to script
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your `DocumentRoot` to point to the `public` directory?

Comment: would be the best version..
but often not possible with shared hosting...