# Laravel route not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I have two routes, one works, the other does not and I cannot figure out why.

The first one works, when I visit the home page the view is displayed as intended.

```
Route::get('/', array('as' => 'homepage', function()
{
    return View::make('home');

}));
```

This second one comes up with a `NotFoundHttpException` error

```
Route::get('about', array('as' => 'aboutpage', function()
{
    return View::make('about');

}));
```

My other Laravel project works fine with this formatting and the home page works fine. If I visit `localhost/laravel/public/index.php/about` it works but `localhost/laravel/public/about does not.

I'm using WAMP and Apache module rewrite_module is on. I have restarted it multiple times.

Comment: is AllowOverride set to all ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in **.htaccess** file of your project:-

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: That was already in there when Laravel created all the files.

Comment: This code is working fine in my Project. There is one more question on stack overflow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15498513/apache-rewrite-for-laravel-public Try it.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to do this:

1-try `return 'hello'` instead of the page:

```
Route::get('about', array('as' => 'aboutpage', function()
{
    return 'hello';
}));
```

2-try to do this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16897504/laravel-quick-start-guide-route-not-working)

Comment: Gave that a shot too but same issue kept occurring. What I ended up doing was just creating a new project and then copy and pasting the exact same code into it and it worked. It's really bizarre because the first project was a brand new one too.

Comment: No, the same thing happens. I just restarted the project and copied my code into it and it works. I have no idea what the reason was.

Comment: @MichaelN, OK I will remove this Answer

Answer (score 0):

1) go to the httpd.conf file of the server and remove hash from line showing below

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

2)and replace AllowOverride none to  AllowOverride All in same httpd.conf file