# Apache Laravel configuration issue

Tags: php, laravel, apache2, config

I am having an issue with getting Laravel to work properly with Apache2. This is my config file, but whenever it go to my domain I see directory list, and I need to enter to portfolio/public to see the app. That's also what the url become (my-website.com/portfolio/public/).
Is there any way I can fix this?
I've been trying to deploy this app for 3 days and still had no success...

Great Thanks!

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName  my-domain.com
    ServerAlias www.my-domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/portfolio/public

<Directory /var/www/html/portfolio/public>
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<Directory /var/www/html/portfolio/public>
    Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
<Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
    AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: Your title and question conflicts. In Your **title** you told about **nginx** configuration and in question you are asking for **apache** configuration

Answer (score 0):

This might help you

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/index.php/$1 [L]
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15498513/apache-rewrite-for-laravel-public/15499862#15499862)